# MariaDB / Laravel 5 best engine for storing tags

Tags: php, laravel, mariadb

Hello i want store tags in db.

The searching for posts will be based on tags.
Then i am searching something for: consistency and performance
Unfortunately it will be nice have foreign keys or some alternatives for it.
I try it with Aria engine, but this don't support foreign keys.

Migration file looks like:

```
    Schema::create('tags', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->engine = 'Aria';
        $table->increments('id')->nullable();
        $table->string('tag',100);
        $table->unique('tag');
    });

    Schema::create('post_tag', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->engine = 'Aria';
        $table->integer('post_id')->unsigned()->index();
        $table->foreign('post_id')->references('id')->on('posts')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->integer('tag_id')->unsigned()->index();
        $table->foreign('tag_id')->references('id')->on('tags')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->primary(['post_id', 'tag_id']);
    });
```

Comment: Did you read https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/foreign-keys ?

Comment: Sure. I use Laracast tutorial from this website: https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-5-fundamentals/episodes/21

Comment: use mariadb or any database for permanently storing.
but once saved you load it to a memory cache like redis and then use redis store to query

Comment: Is there better solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest that "tags" do not need `FOREIGN KEYS`.  You will have one place where you insert tags; you will get that code right and won't need the costly checking all the time.

Instead of having a `CASCADING DELETE`, just leave excess rows in `Tags`.  Please spell out the `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and `SELECTs` you envision.  From those, we can better discuss the merits of *first* the schema, and only *second* which Engine to use.

Use `INSERT IGNORE` or `INSERT .. ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ..` to insert, without dups, tags.

Removing no-longer-wanted tags is more challenging; FKs cannot achieve such.  (Hence, another argument for simply leaving them in place.)

If there is nothing more than a tag, it *may* not be worth it to normalize tags.

Comment: The reason is - many articles can have same tag and articles can create new tag if doesn't exist. In this case is important don't have duplicates and delete what we don't need. But if is there better way let me know. Don't have idea which is the best way for it.

Comment: What about triggers? Maybe this is not good option to delete, but can work. But what about the performance? This can make serious issues. Not sure if we can use it for tags. Anyway i think the FK is not good way to solve it as you mentioned too.

Comment: My answer includes performance.  (This goes for virtually all answers I give on this forum.)  Even if half the Tags are no longer used, the performance hit is insignificant.  Even the wasted disk space is small compared to the size of all the tables combined.